# My Whole App Crashes When I Click My Play Again Button

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I was making something similar to tic tac toe and everything is working and all but this play again button is not working and crashes the whole app. I tried making it again and I tried making a separate method to log it when pressed and it was working but it is not working with play again button.

My play button code is below with pictures of the code and what error happens when I click the button.

```
public void playAgain(View view) {

    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);

    TextView winnerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerView);

    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    winnerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);

        counter.setImageDrawable(null);

    }

    Arrays.fill(gameState, 2);

    activePlayer = 0;
    gameActive = true;

}
```

[image: This Is My playAgain Button Code.]

[image: But When I Press My Play Again Button, It Crashes And Says TO Open App Again]

Comment: I'd say that you have imported or are using the wrong version of `GridLayout` as the one in the XML and the one used in the code don't match. (That's basically what the error log says.)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Yeah, You Are Right, I Changed It And It Is Working.

Comment: Please paste the code and stack trace into the question as TEXT. Do not post images of text. They are difficult to read and impossible to search on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view has androidx GridLayout but inside the activity, android GridLayout is being used to get the view which leads to crash due to casting error.

I agree that changing the import in Activity will fix your problem but make sure that you want to use androidx GridLayout and not Android GridLayout according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace **import android.widget.GridLayout;**

by

**import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;**